# Flutter - Show ripple effect in IconButton over gradient

Tags: flutter, dart, background, gradient, iconbutton

I'm trying to create a back button using an `IconButton` over a gradient, but the ripple effect shows below the gradient which is not the desired behavior. I've seen similar problems which can be resolved using the `Material` widget but it can only accept one color and not a gradient.

This image shows how the ripple effect should look like, but it doesn't have the gradient.
[image: Ripple no gradient]

This image shows the gradient over the text, but also over the ripple effect.
[image: Gradient incorrect ripple]

The correct order should be `IconButton` > `Ripple` > `Gradient` > `Text`

Is there a way to achieve this?

Here's a minimal code to reproduce the issue:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  Text("Lorem ipsum", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28)),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 72,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                      Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                      Theme.of(context).canvasColor.withOpacity(0),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () => print("pop"),
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try create your own Icon button with `InkWell`

```
child: Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  child: Material(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: InkWell(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      onTap: () {
        print("pop");
      },
      splashColor: Colors.green,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]